# Delphi / Indy - Implement RFC1006 communication

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, rfc

I have already implemented a working TCP server and TCP client using Indy components (http://www.indyproject.org).

These work quite fine, but now I need to enhance this communication to follow the specification of RFC 1006 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1006).

As far as I see, this is currently not implemented in Indy. I like the structure and behaviour of Indy, so I'm evaluating what it takes to make it compatible with RFC 1006.

So my first question is, has anybody done that before?

If not, would it be sufficent to add read and write methods to the IOHandler which wrap the RFC data around my user data, or is an Intercept the way to go?

Comment: RFC 1006 is just a framing mechanism on top of TCP. You can implement it in your own code on top of Indy.  No need to alter the IOHandler's code.  When you want to send data, wrap it in the necessary frame, and then send the whole thing to the IOHandler.  When you want to read data, read a full frame from the IOHandler and then decode it as needed.

Comment: HeyRemy thanks for your response. I think that might be the best way to implement this communication frame. I'll see how well it works out.